# What are the conditions for a functional dependency to exist?

Tags: relational-theory

Let be a relation R of scheme: R(A,B,C,D,E) and r an instance of the relation. What functional dependencies verify r?

[image]

Observing the functional dependencies that r verify are  doesn't show that they exists on R and are verified by all possible instances of R.

The definition of a functional dependency is:

[image: DF definition]

I said that there is:

A→E, C→A, B→E, C→D, C→E, D→E, C → A, C→B

AB→D, AB→E, AC→B, AD→D, AD→E, BC→A, BC→D, BC→E, BD→ A, BD→C, BD→E, DE→A, DE→ C

ABC→D, ABC→ E, ABD→E, ABE→D

But I don't know if they do exist, **I don't know what to do to verify if they actually exists**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from comments on the question by [Renzo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68986/renzo) and [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)*</sub>

---

The definition of functional dependencies requires that they must hold for every possible instance.

From an instance, you **cannot** find the functional dependencies that hold in a certain relation schema.

You also missed `A → D`.